# All features are positive in retention model

Tags: machine-learning, retention

Recently I tried to build a model to analyze the importance and effect of features of my app.

Features are about user behaviors which includes pages that users have viewed,  buttons that users have clicked and so on.

In my linear model, I found that almost all features have positive effects. In the other word, the more active the higher probability for users to stay.

Under this condition, ads have also became a positive feature.

Users who have viewed several ads are more likely to stay than those who haven't viewed any ads just because they are more active on my app.

So I want to know how to design the metrics to evaluate the indeed effect of every feature.

Comment: You probably get more help at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Principal component analysis is what you need. It ranks the features in order of their impact on your model.
[This paper](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf) can help you to get familiar with it.